# ODE with non-continuous right hand side

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

My brother asked me a question which I didn't know the answer to.

Are there theorems about existence, uniqueness and stability of solutions of ODEs of the followin type

$$
\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} = f(t,y,\frac{dy}{dt})H(g(y)), 
$$

where $f$ and $g$ are Lipschitz functions and $H$ is the Heaviside function?

If there are no general theorems that could apply, how does one analyze these problems for given $f,g$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible approach.

Choose    smooth approximations  of  $H$. For example   consider a smooth function

$$ \eta:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$$

such that

$$\eta (t)=0,\;\;\forall t\leq 0$$

$$\eta(t)=1,\;\;\forall t\geq 1.$$

Now define

$$H_\varepsilon(t)= \eta(t/\varepsilon)$$

Then

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\searrow 0} H_\varepsilon (t) =H(t),\;\;\forall t\neq 0$$.

Now investigate the above equation with $H$ replaced with $H_\varepsilon$ an hope that you  understand what happens     when $\varepsilon \searrow 0$.

On the other hand, there is a large class of   evolution equations with discountinuous  right-hand side described by the so called maximally monotone operators.   For  2nd  order equations    such as yours, one of the most influential papers is

> Barbu, Viorel Existence theorems for a
>   class of two point boundary problems. 
>   J. Differential Equations 17 (1975),
>   236–257.

For the  general theory of     evolution equations involving  maximal monotone operators the best sources are

> Barbu, Viorel  Nonlinear
>   differential equations of monotone
>   types in Banach spaces.  Springer
>   Monographs in Mathematics. Springer,
>   New York, 2010. x+272 pp.
>
> Brezis, Haim  Opérateurs maximaux
>   monotones et semi-groupes de
>   contractions dans les espaces de
>   Hilbert. (French)  North-Holland
>   Mathematics Studies, No. 5. Notas de
>   Matemática (50). North-Holland
>   Publishing Co., Amsterdam-London;
>   American Elsevier Publishing Co.,
>   Inc., New York, 1973. vi+183 pp

Answer (score 1):

Your brother needs to provide more specific questions that he wants answered. But here are a few thoughts.

Suppose you want to prove existence and uniqueness of the initial value problem. The initial data will imply a value for $H(g(y))$. You can use the standard theorem to solve the initial value problem and extend the solution until $g(y) = 0$. At that point, check the sign of $g'(y)y'$. If it is nonzero, then you can just use the limiting values of $y$ and $y'$ to solve the initial value problem starting from that point. The fact that $y$ and $y'$ are being extended continuously implies that the ODE is being solved at least in the weak sense, and that's usually all that is needed.

If $g(y)$ does not change sign when it vanishes, things get more complicated. But that's something your brother should worry about only if he really does encounter it.